# How to append element in opener window's form using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is it possible to append a HTML element into an opener window's form(which does not have an id or name) using JQuery. I tried the following code, it worked for submit but does not work for append.

**Not working:**

```
$( "form:first" , window.opener.document).append('<div></div>');
```

**Working:**

```
$( "form:first" , window.opener.document).submit();
```

Comment: Try `window.opener.$( "form:first" , window.opener.document).append('<div></div>');`

Comment: Nope, still not working :(

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: Nope, I couldn't notice anything. It just went on submitting the opener form by ignoring the append line

Comment: When I use an Id for the form it seems to work fine :S

Comment: Sorry, it works fine now. The code was within a loop which was not executing :S